# servor error in loging while allready loging in another window

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice, impex

throwing server error, in 
1st tab situation login and logout and
2.login again in another tab,
while trying to login in 1st again throwing servor error

https://apparel-uk.localhost:9002/en/j_spring_security_check

This error is because of the invalid CSRF token which is not in match with the session's csrf token.
how to hadle this .

Comment: Does the same thing happen in higher test environments too ? I doubt it. Such issues generally happen in local because of session data conflict.

Comment: Where are you getting this error? Is it storefront or backoffice?